# VSCode thinks that some imports are not used in TSX files, but they are

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, stenciljs, tsx

I'm working on a StencilJS project (tsx files) and VSCode incorrectly informs me that some declarations are never used

[image]

In the screenshot it complains about the Class name, but I get a similar message for the import of Component

> 'Component' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match

But the project compiles just fine. I also have created a new stencil project from scratch, which doesn't have those issues :(

The problem this is causing me now is that when I hit `save` all the unused imports are removed, which is incorrect (=build failing)

Inside `.eslintrc.json` I noticed that I have

```
 "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "import", "unused-imports"],
 "rules": {
    "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error",
```

If I set "error" to `0` the errors change into warnings.

Any suggestions what might cause this weirdness?

Comment: Gut feeling is that VS is getting confused by the decorator? The @ symbol. What happens if you use Component without an @? Does it stop complaining?

Comment: Indeed, if I remove the `@` the Component import and class are not unused anymore.

Comment: I've added some content from .eslintrc.json

Comment: Gut feeling that is one or more of TypeScript / eslint / @typescript-eslint is old and has a bug and that upgrading will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What about seperating the class definition and the export statement?

```js
    class MyFoo {
      @Element() host: HTMLElement;
}

...

module.exports = MyFoo;
/* OR if there are other exports, lump them together */
module.exports = {
    ...,
    ...,
    MyFoo
}
```

Comment: Splitting doesn't seem to help, except that the unused class is gone

Comment: Yes, I was trying to fix your unused class problem - I think the Component issue is a bug in typescript lint module, rather than anything you did wrong. But the MyFoo class can be fixed.

Comment: ok I see. I'll first try the update suggestion! Thnx